# Servlets - How can form elements passed to a servlet not be incorporated in a URL when accessing the server

Tags: java, servlets

I'm just wondering how it would be possible for any elements passed to a servlet to not be incorporated in a url when accessing a servlet, thanks.

Comment: Please don’t deface your questions by removing all information.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `POST` request instead of a `GET` request.

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP POST** method is used to pass data enclosed in the body of the request message.
In your html form use method="post" like below,

```
<form action="HelloServlet" method="post">
```

For more details, See how HTTP POST method works [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP))